# dysfunctional jQuery function without any clue in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this function which I intend to use to disable a button having met certain conditions.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

     <script type ="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

             //TEXT BOX 1
         $('#<%=txtAmount_VH.ClientID%>').keyup(function (e) {

             $vhamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_VH.ClientID%>').val();
             $mxamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_MX.ClientID%>').val();
             $obamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_OB.ClientID%>').val();
             $spamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_SP.ClientID%>').val();

             $totamnt = $('#<%=txtTotalSecurityDeposit.ClientID%>').val();
             $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
             if ($sum <= $totamnt) {
                 $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
             }
         });
             //TEXT BOX 2
             $('#<%=txtAmount_MX.ClientID%>').keyup(function (e) {

             $vhamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_VH.ClientID%>').val();
             $mxamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_MX.ClientID%>').val();
             $obamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_OB.ClientID%>').val();
             $spamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_SP.ClientID%>').val();

             $totamnt = $('#<%=txtTotalSecurityDeposit.ClientID%>').val();
             $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
             if ($sum <= $totamnt) {
                 $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
             }
         });

             //TEXT BOX 3
             $('#<%=txtAmount_OB.ClientID%>').keyup(function (e) {

             $vhamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_VH.ClientID%>').val();
             $mxamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_MX.ClientID%>').val();
             $obamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_OB.ClientID%>').val();
             $spamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_SP.ClientID%>').val();

             $totamnt = $('#<%=txtTotalSecurityDeposit.ClientID%>').val();
             $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
             if ($sum <= $totamnt) {
                 $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
             }
         });

             //TEXT BOX 4
             $('#<%=txtAmount_SP.ClientID%>').keyup(function (e) {

             $vhamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_VH.ClientID%>').val();
             $mxamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_MX.ClientID%>').val();
             $obamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_OB.ClientID%>').val();
             $spamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_SP.ClientID%>').val();

             $totamnt = $('#<%=txtTotalSecurityDeposit.ClientID%>').val();
             $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
             if ($sum <= $totamnt) {
                 $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
             }
         });
        </script>
```

Also, console isn't helping much.

> I want the function to disable a button whenever the sum of values for
>   textboxes is larger than another particular textbox. However, that is
>   not happening at all.

Am I missing something obvious or is it more than that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `parseInt` in condition for doing that correctly like below:

```
if (parseInt($sum) <= parseInt($totamnt)) {
    $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

**Edit**

You can check all of inputs in same way.

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {

    $vhamnt = $('#txtAmount_VH').val();
    $mxamnt = $('#txtAmount_MX').val();
    $obamnt = $('#txtAmount_OB').val();
    $spamnt = $('#txtAmount_SP').val();

    $totamnt = $('#txtTotalSecurityDeposit').val();
    $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
    if (parseInt($sum) <= parseInt($totamnt)) {
        $('#btnAddAmount').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/6r2myw8b/8/)

**Edit 1**

This is a test markup that I checked and it works for me properly

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox Class="checkAmount" ID="txtAmount_VH" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox Class="checkAmount" ID="txtAmount_MX" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox Class="checkAmount" ID="txtAmount_OB" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox Class="checkAmount" ID="txtAmount_SP" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox Class="checkAmount" ID="txtTotalSecurityDeposit" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddAmount" Text="AddAmount" runat="server" />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.checkAmount').keyup(function(e) {

            $vhamnt = $('#txtAmount_VH').val();
            $mxamnt = $('#txtAmount_MX').val();
            $obamnt = $('#txtAmount_OB').val();
            $spamnt = $('#txtAmount_SP').val();

            $totamnt = $('#txtTotalSecurityDeposit').val();
            $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
            if (parseInt($sum) <= parseInt($totamnt)) {
                $('#btnAddAmount').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: @fasih I added a fiddle to my answer and I checked in my computer. It's works properly. Please see this fiddle for understanding it better.

Comment: That fiddle won't work with server side controls because it is getting triggered at element level.

Comment: @fasih I know it doesn't work in server side, but `asp:TextBox` rendered to input and you can handle it by specific class attribute instead of `$('input')`.

Comment: Nope. Not working, here is one asp:TextBox, others are similar except obvious differences

`
<td style="width: 100px"> <asp:TextBox class ="input" ID="txtAmount_VH" MaxLength="9" runat="server" Width="100px" Style="text-align: right" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onfocus="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onkeyup="words.innerHTML=convertNumberToWords(this.value)" onfocusout="myFunctionn()"></asp:TextBox> </td> `

Comment: And here's the function

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input').keyup(function (e) {
                $obamnt = $('#<%=txtAmount_OB%>').val();
                $totamnt = $('#<%=txtTotalSecurityDeposit%>').val();

                $sum = $vhamnt + $mxamnt + $obamnt + $spamnt;
                If(parseInt($sum) > parseInt($totamnt)) Then {
                    $('#<%=btnAddAmount.ClientID%>').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

Comment: couldn't write full function because of char limit

Comment: @fasih I added my asp code to my answer for clarifying my comments. Please see it again.